# Javascript change commas for points and points for commas?

Tags: javascript

I want to convert all commas in a string in points and vice-versa. However I don't know how to do it since I get all commas or points after the first change.

```
"1.000,20" should become "1,000.20"
```

How can this be done?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try

```
"1.000,20".replace(/[\.,]/g, function (m) { return m == '.' ? ',' : '.' })
```

which uses the callback function option of `replace()`

Comment: much smarter answer :) i was thinking of a regex solution but forgot about the callback function. nicely done

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var str = "1,000.20";

//Split into components based on a period
var components = str.split('.');

//Iterate through each component, replacing commas with periods
var length = components.length;

for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
   components[i] = components[i].replace(",", ".");
}

//Array.join can be slow but still useful - join with commas
str = components.join(",");
```